# No Response Header in DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, web-api-contrib

I'm trying to log the HTTP Response Headers of my Web API project.

The project is developed by VS2012, .NET 4.5 and ASP.NET MVC 4.

I've wrote a `DelegatingHandler` subclass like this:

```
public class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        // Execute the request
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            var response = task.Result;
            return response;
        });
    }
}
```

However, the problem is, I can't get the header values from the `response`. `response.Headers` is an empty collection, `response.Content.Headers` contains nothing but a key named `Content-Type`, and `HttpContext.Current` is `null`.

I've seen the code of [WebAPIContrib](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib/MessageHandlers/LoggingHandler.cs) which use the same logic to log the headers, but their code does not seem to work either.

So how should I trace the HTTP Response Headers in Web API project?

Comment: Same problem here. Do you have a solution?

Comment: No, never found that out

Comment: I've solved the issue by sending the response headers to the client instead of changing the response message in the delegating handler. Much easier in my javascript framework too!

Answer (score 4):

> Message handlers are called in the same order that they appear in
>   `MessageHandlers` collection. Because they are nested, the response
>   message travels in the other direction. That is, the last handler is
>   the first to get the response message.

Make sure that the logging handler is registered early in the pipeline. Preferably first.

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new LoggingHandler(...));

        //...add other handlers
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageHandler1());
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageHandler2());

        // Other code not shown...
    }
}
```

That way any other handlers would have their chance to populate the response and have that info logged.

You can also simplify the class using async/await syntax to make accessing the response cleaner.

```
public class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler {
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

        //...Extract and log request
        LogRequest(request);

        // Send the request on to the inner handler(s) and get the response
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        //...Extract details from response for logging
        LogResponse(response);

        return response;
    }

    private void LogRequest(HttpRequestMessage request) {
        //... code removed for brevity
    }

    private void LogResponse(HttpResponseMessage response) {
        //... code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

Should be able to access the necessary details from the response before returning it.

Reference : [HTTP Message Handlers in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers)

Answer (score 2):

Try out the below code.

```
return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(
                        task =>
                        {

                            var headers = task.Result.ToString();
                            var body = task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                            // RETURN THE ORIGINAL RESULT
                            var response = task.Result;
                            return response;
                        }
            );
```

Comment: This is similar to the second example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers#example-adding-a-custom-response-header

Answer (score 0):

You must look at the right place:

```
request.Content.Headers.ContentType
```

Assuming there's a `Content-Type: application/json` request header, then the aforementioned will return `"application/json"`.

So basically some headers are associated with the Content and that's where you should be reading them from.

Same is true for the response headers. Depending on their type you might need to extract them from the response content (for requests that return body)

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentType
```

Comment: Won't that get **request** header? I need to log all response headers, not just ContentType but response.Headers is empty

Comment: Same thing: `response.Content.Headers`

Comment: response.Content.Headers contains only ContentType. Are other headers (content-length, cache, etc) added by iis express and so there is no way to get them?